# front image inherits the properties from backgrund image in css

Tags: html, css, background

i've used the blur filter effect in a div's background image,
but the filter automatically applies to the picture in the front too

```css
.backg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg");
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="backg">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
</div>
</body>
```

**i want the filter only to be only applied in the background**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this code will be helpful for you

```css
.backg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg");
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.content img {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="backg"></div>
<div class="content">
  <img  src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.backg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
.backg:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-image: url("https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg");
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
  filter: blur(10px);
}
.backg img {
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="backg">
  <img src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/1/590x/dog-650299.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi Rupak
add the background in before or after of div, currently you are making the div property blur which makes everything blur it contains.
hopw you find the solution :)